# Ошибка в программе

Tags: objective-c

Написал программу, выдает ошибку через раз, да и памяти много использует.
Хочу чтобы он рандомно задавал значения a и b  такие чтобы они делились без остатка.
Что не так ? Почему ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    int a,b,y;
    int buffer;

    startLoop:

    a = arc4random() % 100;
    b = arc4random() % 10;

    if (a % b != 0) { goto startLoop; }

     else {

    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"%i / %i",a,b);

    scanf("%d", &buffer);

    y = a/b;

    if (buffer == y) {

        NSLog(@"True ! %i",y);

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"Wrong ! %i",y);

    }

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSLog(@"%f", -timeInterval);

    if (-timeInterval > 5.) {NSLog(@"Too late !");}
    else

    {}
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: goto ???  для начала обрати внимание на форматирование и перейди на нормальные операторы цикла, тебе же легче будет разобраться в своем коде

Comment: Перед вычислением остатка советую проверять `b` на 0.

Answer (score 1):

А не реализация ли это знаменитого алгоритма Бабушкина? =)

К b добавь единичку, так будет возвращаться значение от одного до 10:

```
b = arc4random() % 10 +1;
```

И я бы рекомендовал **while**:

```
do {
    a = arc4random() % 100 + 1;
    b = arc4random() % 10 + 1;
} while (a % b);
```

Comment: не знаю чей это алгоритм)
я самоучка, так что сам до такого додумался)
тоже сначало хотел while, но не додумался как

спасибо !